# g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-diagnostics-color’

Tags: compiler-errors

When i am trying to run a simple program to g++ compiler (installed in ubuntu) i get the following error :

```
**g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-diagnostics-color’**
```

I would like to know where is the configuration of the compiler in order to be able to disable the attribute ‘-fno-diagnostics-color’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i did an upgrade to my gcc following the tutorial below:

https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91